# link error when using ITK Library with MSYS2

Tags: c++, cmake, msys2, itk

I am looking to compile a program using ITK with MSYS2 under Windows. When I generate my makefile with CMAKE, I get this error.

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:36 (target_link_libraries):
Target "itkComparaison" links to:

GTest::GTest

but the target was not found.  Possible reasons include:

* There is a typo in the target name.
* A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target.
* An ALIAS target is missing.
```

with this CMakeLists

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(itkComparaison)
find_package(ITK REQUIRED)
include(${ITK_USE_FILE})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

add_executable(
    itkComparaison
    main.cpp
    ....h
    ....cpp
)

find_package(ITK CONFIG REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(itkComparaison ${ITK_LIBRARIES})
```

Have you ever encountered this error?

Comment: Correct name of the target for link with GTest library is `GTest::gtest`, see their [README](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/googletest/README.md).

Comment: You have `find_package(ITK)` twice. That looks suspicious.

Comment: Also, why not use `set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)` for C++11?